# Docker Compose Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error:

`web_1  | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

However the image is being created. I want to have a Rails application, and for the Docker files to live outside the rails application. I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app/Gemfile Gemfile

# Install Gems
RUN bundle install
ADD . /app
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file I have the Following configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.1 # To Edit - Default is postgresql.
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And for the Gemfile I have the following code:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the Rails or Ruby version. I also see that the Gemfile is there once I go into the container and run `ls` so is not that theres no Gemfile.

`root@ab38d643df47:/app# ls
Dockerfile  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.md  app  docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Is the `bundle install` working fine?. If not volume the application have an issue check it.

Comment: `bundle install` is working

Comment: ```Step 5/6 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Running in a655b9d92691``` it installed

Comment: Try changing dockerfile line to:  COPY Gemfile Gemfile  #This is because your workdir is already set to /app

Comment: If you try to ssh in to the container and run `bundle install` from that directory, does it give you the same error?

Comment: Also, I don't _think_ this should be causing your error, but it's kind of against convention to have your Gemfile and .lock live outside of your `app` directory.

Comment: @bkunzi01 that didn't work

Comment: @supremebeing7 they do live within the app I think that is just the COPY to the Dockerfile. ```root@f44f58cc3fca:/app# ls
Dockerfile  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.md  app  docker-compose.yml
root@f44f58cc3fca:/app# cd app
root@f44f58cc3fca:/app/app# ls
Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.md  Rakefile  app  bin  config  config.ru  db  lib  log  package.json  public  storage  test  tmp  vendor
root@f44f58cc3fca:/app/app#```

Comment: Sorry, I misread. So, `bundle install` works during build, but when trying to bring up the container, using `bundle exec` prefix is throwing your error. Can you check what your `BUNDLE_BIN` and `BUNDLE_PATH` values are in the container? you may need to define this in your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @supremebeing7 the error comes when I run `docker compose up -d` which is supposed to start the server

Comment: Correct. And it's starting the server with `bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'`. So, there's a couple things you could try: 1) change that to `bin/rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'`, or 2) figure out where your `bundle` binary is located in the container and make sure that matches the value in `BUNDLE_BIN`

Comment: Use ‘COPY Gemfile Gemfile’ and  change ‘ADD . ./app’ to ‘COPY . .’  Don’t forget to rebuild the image ‘docker-compose build web’

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

WORKDIR app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile

# Install Gems
RUN bundle install
ADD . app
```